# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function exists() on null in

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

when I open myPhpAdmin of xampp on mac, it gives

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function exists()
on null in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php:1544
Stack trace: #0
/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php(2477):
PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->postConnectControl() #1
/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php(358):
PhpMyAdmin\DatabaseInterface->connect(257) #2
/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/index.php(26):
require_once('/opt/lampp/phpm...') #3 {main}
thrown in
/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php
on line 1544
```

Do you know what I should do?

Comment: You are calling exists() on a object which does not exists. Give your code around the lines 1544 in  /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/libraries/classes/DatabaseInterface.php

Comment: ok, you just repeat the error for me, anyway, thanks

Comment: Since XAMPP packages all the components that should be needed for this, you should ask their support folks for help or file a bug report with them directly. They have more knowledge and experience with how they integrate all the components than we do.

Comment: How  do I do that ??